# Issue with Skype and botframework

Tags: c#, botframework, skype

I'm having an issue with the Bot Framework and Skype only. When a user types an apostrophe, my bot gets 'apos' instead of the apostrophe and doesn't recognize the word. I've tried trapping `"apos"` with an `if` statement:

```
if (message.ChannelId == "skype")
{
    message.Text = Regex.Replace(message.Text, @"APOS(?=(m|s|re|t|d|ve))", @"'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

That works in development but not in production. Has anyone run into an issue with apostrophes on Skype, and found a solution?

Comment: You want to look into Encoding, specially HtmlEncoding and then the reverse of that: HttpUtility.Decode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yup, that did it. Cheers.